# Integrate Visa and Mastercard in DJango 1.8 app

Tags: django

I have made a DJango app where I show products, now I want to create a shopping cart where the clients will pay for products and shipping. I found this for visa [Visa checkout](https://developer.visa.com/products/visa_checkout) but i don't how how to use it, and also this for Master Card  [Master card payment gateway service](https://developer.mastercard.com/product/mastercard-payment-gateway-service). I understand that they manage all the security and fraud prevention, that's why I'm thinking in an external plugin. As an extra I found this package for PayPal [Django-Paypal](https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal). Will somebody give me advices or recommend me tutorials for their usage?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use Stripe for the credit card handling?

Here is a Django package for that: https://github.com/kavdev/dj-stripe

Comment: I wrote to them and their services aren't available in my Country, I live in Guatemala, any other sugestion?

Comment: [2CheckOut](https://www.2checkout.com) and [Django Plugin](https://github.com/gjedeer/django-twocheckout) (if it still works) or [WorldPay](http://www.worldpay.com/) and [Django Plugin](https://github.com/MatthewWilkes/django-oscar-worldpay)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, 2checkout has services in my country, but they ask for too much money so I decided to not use their services, but this is a valid solution.